# Плагин для Sublime Text 3. Авто-дополнение в JS

Tags: javascript, sublime-text

Есть ли какой-нибудь плагин для Sublime Text, чтобы допустим я забыл как пишется какой-нибудь метод - был авто-выбор как в IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой плагин: [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + shift + p  instal pack   -->>>>>>SublimeCodeIntel